# R, Confusion Matrix in percent

Tags: r, machine-learning, confusion-matrix, r-caret

In R how to get Confusion Matrix in percent (or fraction of 1).
The "caret" package provides useful function but shows absolute number of samples.

```
library(caret)
data(iris)
T <- iris$Species
P <- sample(iris$Species)
confusionMatrix(P, T)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics
             Reference
Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
setosa         15         16        19
versicolor     19         16        15
virginica      16         18        16
```

Comment: `prop.table(confusionMatrix(P, T)$table, {1|2})`?

Comment: If you have your answer it is courteous to accept so the answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 7):

The caret function is nice if you want all the summary statistics.  If all you care about is the 'percentage' confusion matrix, you can just use `prop.table` and `table`.  Also, for future reference, strictly programming questions should be posted to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) not CrossValidated.

```
prop.table(table(P,T))
> prop.table(table(P,T))
            T
P                setosa versicolor  virginica
  setosa     0.11333333 0.10666667 0.11333333
  versicolor 0.09333333 0.13333333 0.10666667
  virginica  0.12666667 0.09333333 0.11333333
```

If you would like to keep the summary statistics from caret, just you prop.table on the confusion matrix object.

```
prop.table(caret::confusionMatrix(P,T)$table)
```